# Coincidence of the coordinate ring and the set of regular functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

If $X$ is an affine variety, and if we denote by k[X] its coordinate ring and by $O(X)$ the set of regular functions on $X$, then it is well-known that $k[X]\cong O(X)$.
My question is : Do we have the same for (affine) algebraic groups ? How do we prove that?

Answer (score 2):

Well, affine algebraic groups are in particular affine varieties, so of course the same result holds for them.

For non-affine algebraic groups, the ring of regular functions can be very restrictive, and the coordinate ring of a non-affine variety is not really well defined.  For example, a connected abelian variety $G$ is complete (that is, for any variety $Y$, the projection map $G \times Y \rightarrow Y$ is closed), and therefore has trivial global section.

Definitions: if $X$ is a variety, $\mathcal O(X)$ denotes the ring of regular functions on $X$, i.e. morphisms of varieties from $X$ to the variety $k = \mathbb A^1$.

If $X$ is an affine variety, and $X$ is a Zariski closed subset of some $k^n$, then the coordinate ring $k[X]$ is the ring of polynomial functions from $k^n$ to $k$, restricted to $X$.  Equivalently, $X$ is can be identified with the space of maximal ideals (or prime ideals, depending on the formulation) of a finitely generated $k$-algebra $A$, and the coordinate ring $k[X]$ is just $A$.

Comment: If the algebraic group $G$ is connected, then yes it is an affine variety (i.e an irreducible algebraic set ). But what if $G$ is not connected ?

Comment: I see that you assume irreducible as being part of the definition of a variety (which not all authors take).  Three things: even if you do not assume irreducibility as part of the definition of a variety, it is still true that the coordinate ring of an affine variety coincides with its ring of regular functions.  Second, it is false that every connected algebraic group is an affine variety (for example, an elliptic curve).  Third, for non-affine varieties $X$ the notion of a coordinate ring $k[X]$ does not make sense, while the ring of regular functions $\mathcal O(X)$ does make sense.